# Angular Modal Only Works Within Index.html

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

My angular modal is working:

[image]

However, to get it to work, the modal script has to be within my index.html:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

And this is the call in the controller to it:

```
    $scope.addRecipe = function () {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            size: 'sm',
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    return $scope.items;
                }
            }
        });
```

If I create an HTML file and put that above modal script in it, the modal stops showing up. (The page still gets grayed-out but there is no modal.) I've tried putting the HTML file in the root folder (right next to index.html) and I've had it in a separate folder, but it just won't show up. When I try to use this separate file, I change the templateUrl property of the call:

```
'app/partials/recipeAdd.html'
```

And I change the ID in the HTML:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="app/partials/recipeAdd.html">
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If understanding correctly you are saying the html template won't load from server? if so, inspect actual ajax request in dev tools network tab for starters to see what is in response body. Does it also have template script tag in that file or just html?

Comment: The script tag is in the separate HTML file.

Comment: remove the script tag... return raw html only

Comment: If matching script tag or $templateCache entry doesn't exist, an ajax call is made. angular expects html and not to look for another script tag. Same principle applies to all templateUrl use in angular routing or directives

Comment: Thanks, man. That was helpful. If you'd like to post this as the answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is using a template script tag to wrap the html in the remote template file.

When angular is provided a `templateUrl` it will look in `$templateCache` for a matching entry which will also be populated by `ng-template` script tags found in main page as well. If none found it will make an ajax call and expects raw html returned.

This newly acquired template will also be cached in `$templateCache` so further ajax calls are not needed to re-use it